# Why adding the second test in the Double-Checked-Locking?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, synchronization

Refering to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking,
we have:

```
// "Double-Checked Locking" idiom
class Foo {
    private Helper helper;
    public Helper getHelper() {
        if (helper == null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (helper == null) {
                    helper = new Helper();
                }
            }
        }
        return helper;
    }    
    // other functions and members...
}
```

What is the purpose of the second test? Is it really possible that 2 threads could access the same critical section at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two threads cannot access the same critical section at the same time; by definition a critical section is mutually exclusive.

To answer your question, the first `null` test is a cheap test without synchronization, and the second `null` test checks the real state with synchronization.

---

The second test is necessary. Suppose we didn't have it, and the code looked like this:

```
public Helper getHelper() {
    if (helper == null) {
        synchronized(this) {
            helper = new Helper();
        }
    }
    return helper;
}
```

Suppose thread A executes `if (helper == null)` and it tests `true`, so it goes into the `if` block but execution gets suspended. No variables are updated yet.

Then thread B executes `if (helper == null)` and it tests `true`, so it goes into the `if` block. Then it continues execution into the `synchronized` block and initializes the `helper` object and returns.

Now thread A continues execution, goes into the `synchronized` block, overwrites `helper` with a new object, and returns the object.

The problem we have is that `helper` was initialized twice, with different objects.

That's why the second test is necessary.

Comment: Just to avoid that someone simply copies the code of the OP: It is **not 100% correct**, The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) says that you have to declare the variable as `volatile` or use [Initialization on demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom) or a wrapper.

Comment: @jameslarge: The problem with your argument is that the variable `helper` can be seen by thread B to be assigned before the object's fields are visible to thread B - because there is no happens-before relation involved. Thus the `volatile` qualifier *is* necessary.

Comment: @beosign, Oops!  You're right.  I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 2):

To make it more obvious what could happen, consider this code:

```
if (helper == null) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    synchronized(this) {
        if (helper == null) {
            helper = new Helper();
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example so I don't care about `InterruptedException`.

It should be clear that between passing the first test and entering the critical region, there is time for some other thread to come along and enter the critical region first.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all other answers, a very good example is the Thread Safe [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern. You have again the same:

```
public static Singleton getInstanceDC() {
   if (_instance == null) {       // Single Checked
    synchronized (Singleton.class) { 
         if (_instance == null) { // Double checked 
               _instance = new Singleton();
          }
     }
  }
   return _instance;
}
```

So basically performing the lock is a lot more expensive if compared to a  pointer check `instance != null`. The implementation also has to ensure that when the Singleton is initialized there will be no issues resulting from thread race conditions. So the main reason is the performance. If `instance != null` (which will always be the case except the very first time), there is no need to do the expensive lock: Two threads accessing the initialized singleton simultaneously would be synchronized unnecessarily. This picture demonstrates it clear:

[image]

There is a lot [more in Singletons](https://javainsider.wordpress.com/tag/singleton-pattern/) then just the double checking:

- Early and lazy instantiation in singleton pattern
- Singleton and Serialization